# how to install intel corporation 2nd generation core processor family integrated graphics in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: 11.04, drivers, intel

I have recently installed ubuntu 11.04 in a dell inspiron 17R and everything is fine except that the system doesn't recognize additional drivers. It says *no proprietary drivers are in use on this system.*

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev b5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM67 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 (rev 34)
02:00.0 USB Controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 04)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
```

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Why do you need to install additional drivers? Intel cards are supported by default in Ubuntu.

Comment: @Lekensteyn Turn that into an answer before I do ;)

Comment: @Oli: I've no time to make an extended answer, your turn :)

Comment: @Lekensteyn Your wish is my command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the xorg-edgers repository of experimental drivers to update the drivers for your video card. Because the drivers are not guaranteed the experimental operation, can solve problems but also created new problems, but you sure are using the latest release of the same.

I own a laptop with this graphics card and recently updated the drivers for this repository, where there was no problem. If you want to perform the update run the command

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

And restart your computer. After the restart the driver will be updated.

Your video card also has the technology SNA - Sandy Bridge New Acceleration Architecture that improves some acceleration features. After updating the driver to use this feature enter the commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sarvatt/intel-sna && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade-y
```

Use this [at your own risk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out), please understand that PPAs can break your system.

Answer (score 3):

The additional drivers tool is there for proprietary (that is non-free, closed source) drivers that can't be distributed on the Ubuntu CD.

Intel graphics drivers, including those for the Intel GMA 4500MHD in your laptop, are part of the default Linux Kernel and X should have its counterpart installed by default (the `xserver-xorg-video-intel` package).

#### In short: you shouldn't need to do anything. It should work out the box.

If it's not, you might want to start another question, detailing the problem a little more explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Intel created a gui that updates more than what you get with backports.

```
sudo apt-get install intel-linux-graphics-installer
```

You can refer to this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270658/xserver-xorg-video-intel-not-installed) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I did what he mentions in this website: https://theiszm.wordpress.com/2010/06/27/glx-missing-on-display/

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel  libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
sudo update-alternatives --remove gl_conf /usr/lib/nvidia-current/ld.so.conf
```

It worked great!