# xserver-xorg-video-intel not installed

Tags: 12.04, intel, xserver

I keep receiving a crash report and when I view the details it says xserver-xorg-video-intel not installed.
I receive this crash report constantly.  5-10 times in a row.  It is very annoying and I need to find a way to stop this.  I am using Ubuntu 12.04 clean install.

If I try to install (sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel), it says

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-video-intel : Depends: xorg-video-abi-11
                            Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.10.99.901)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a graphics gui by intel for download.

```
sudo apt-get install intel-linux-graphics-installer
```

However, it is for the 32bit system but if you install on a 64, your touchpad mouse will become unresponsive.
You can then do

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This fixed the xserver crashes and the mouse wasn't disabled after every reboot.  If your mouse is disabled, do

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

But after re-downloading from the ppa, the issue resolved with the touchpad.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get check` will "verify there are no broken dependencies." - `man apt-get`

Try that and `sudo apt-get install -f`. That will try to fix these broken dependencies. If it doesn't solve the problem please post the output of the commands.

Answer (score 0):

the graphics gui by intel helped me.
My bug seems to be related to my graphic card sandybridge.
Here is the launchpad bug report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1140716