# Touchpad is unresponsive on every reboot

Tags: 12.04, touchpad, xserver

I downloaded the intel graphics utility to fix the xserver-xorg-video crash and then my touchpad was unresponsive on every reboot.

In order to get the touchpad back, I had to

```
dustin@dustin:~$ sudo modprobe -r psmouse
dustin@dustin:~$ sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

Is there a fix or do I need to do this every time I log on?

Comment: The question is the last line of the post: Is there a fix or do I need to do this every time I log on?

Comment: I think you are looking for [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/262364/33871) :)

Comment: I actually downloaded the xserver-xorg file off ppa which doesn't update all the files like the intel graphics gui does.  Whatever file it overwrites removes the problem and the xserver-xorg-video crash doesn't happen again either.

Comment: Here is what I have down to solve the xerver-xorg crashes and get my touchpad functioning with editing the file in /etc   [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/270658/xserver-xorg-video-intel-not-installed/270667#270667)