# can only start with nomodeset

Tags: 14.04, graphics, intel

I am running ubuntu 14.04.1 on an intel Atom machine.
When I start I have to set nomodeset or it boots to a black screen. But even then I only get a 800x600 resolution and everything graphics related feels very slow.

`lshw -class display` output:

```
*-display UNGEFORDERT   
   Beschreibung: VGA compatible controller
   Produkt: Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display
   Hersteller: Intel Corporation
   Physische ID: 2
   Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:02.0
   Version: 0c
   Breite: 32 bits
   Takt: 33MHz
   Fähigkeiten: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   Konfiguration: latency=0
   Ressourcen: memory:d0000000-d03fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f080(Größe=8)
```

`lspci | grep VGA` output:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0c)
```

All articles I could find said that `nomodeset` is only required if the graphics card driver isn't installed correctly. But shouldn't intel graphics cards be supported by default?

How do I get the system to use the graphics card correctly?
Also I can't enter suspend mode, maybe this is related.

Comment: What video card is this ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen It's an intel onboard card. The output of lshw is unfortunately in german.

Comment: that does not show the graphicx card. Run `lspci | grep VGA`

Comment: @bodhi.zazen It's the same one

Comment: Install xserver-xorg-video-intel `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel`. If that fails, you will need to file a bug report against xserver-xorg-video-intel. You can also try http://askubuntu.com/questions/270658/xserver-xorg-video-intel-not-installed

Comment: Some people had to update their bios , see http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=299995