# Resolution is stuck at 1024 x 768

Tags: graphics, xorg, resolution, 14.10

I have my laptop duel-booted Windows 7/Ubuntu 14.10 running with the KDE desktop (although this problem was present before I changed from Gnome). This problem has been present ever since I first installed Linux. My computer supports resolutions up to 1366 x 768, but my Ubuntu states its maximum resolution as 1024 x 768. If anyone knows of a way to fix this, please help.

Result of running `xrandr`:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 800 x 600, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       0.0*
   800x600       61.0
```

Result of running `lspci | grep VGA` (for finding the graphics card)

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

Any help is much appreciated, and if any more information is required, please ask.

***EDIT:*** I just tried running the Intel Linux graphics installer to see if my graphics cards needed updating (though they should have been up-to-date already). The graphics installer then said that my distribution was not supported. Does Intel support 14.10?

***EDIT #2:*** I found that Intel has not released official drivers for Ubuntu 14.10 (I had thought originally that they had and that I had installed them). I am going to back up my computer and do a fresh install back to 14.04 to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Your examples refer to terminal commands.  Have you tried the GUI "Displays" utility located under System Settings?

Comment: @gyropyge, I have tried changing the resolution under the GUI display utility, but the only options for the resolution are 1024x768 and 800x600

Comment: Have you tried the "Additional Drivers" option under System Settings?

Comment: @gyropyge, It says that no additional drivers are availible

Comment: That might be the case, but sometimes it can be wrong.  Please respond with the brand and model of graphics card or the chipset if on the mainboard.

Comment: @gyropyge, I believe that what you are asking for is in the original question (the `lspci | grep VGA` result)

Comment: You may be right, I mean, "Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)" might be the chipset, but frankly, it looks rather vague.  If your install "System Profiler and Benchmark" you might find a more exacting result.

Comment: @gyropyge, Would the information your looking for be under the DMI tab, under the Board section?

Comment: Yes, in the DMI tab under the board section there should be a chip number.  That could be very helpful.  In the meantime I've looked up your general information and found another answer on this very site which offers some insights regarding a repository you can add to install extra drivers semi-automatically.

Comment: @gyropyge, It does not have a chip number, but it says that the name is K54C, which might be what you want. However, I looked around a bit more, and under the PCI Devices list, the VGA Compatible Controller listed was the same as in my result above. Also, would you mind posting a link to that other post that you think would be helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was causing the problem. The drivers weren't installed correctly. I found out that Intel does not have support for Ubuntu 14.10, only 14.04. I did a fresh install of 14.04 and now everything is working again.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, sorry!  I have company here and I was a little distracted.  Here is [the link I referred to](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54464/how-to-install-intel-corporation-2nd-generation-core-processor-family-integrated) in my comment which might help you to make your graphics controller work better.